# それぞれのレビューキューに項目が積まれる条件は？

Tags: サポート, レビュー

例えば、クローズずみの質問を編集することで、それは再オープンのレビューキューに積まれるのだと認識しています。私の認識が正しかったとして、例えば新規のユーザーに対して、以下のように説明することができます。「クローズされたので、質問を編集してください。編集すると、自動的にレビューのキューに積まれます。」

上の例で言いたかったことは、それぞれのレビューキューにどのタイミングでレビュー項目が積まれていくのかを知っておくと、余計な手間を省けるのではないか、ということです。私の認識だと、この条件についてまとめて説明した記事は、（少なくとも (meta.)ja.stackoverflow.com には) 存在していないという認識なので、この質問をしています。

Comment: 英語版があるはずです。探したら、ここにリンクを貼り付けます。

Comment: 英語版の関連ページを見つけたので [http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: @cuttlefish44 日本語版にもあります: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## クローズ票

- enqueue: クローズ票の投票 or 「クローズする必要があります」通報
- dequeue: 質問がクローズされる or 十分な数(3？)の「オープンのままにする」レビュー or 「編集」レビュー

## 初めての投稿

- enqueue: 新規ユーザーの投稿

## 遅延回答

- enqueue: 質問よりもずっと遅延して投稿された回答

## 低品質な投稿

- enqueue: システムが自動判断 or 「品質が低すぎる」通報 or 「回答になっていません」通報
- dequeue: 投稿がクローズされる(質問の場合) or 投稿が削除される(回答の場合) or 十分な数(2？)の「良い」レビュー or モデレータが通報キューから何かしら対応を行う

## 再オープン票

- enqueue: 再オープン票投票 or 「改善待ち」状態の質問の編集
  <sub>（つまり、クローズ後5日経って「クローズ済み」になったものは編集してもキューに積まれません）</sub>
- dequeue: 再オープン or 十分な数の「クローズのままにする」レビュー

## 提案された編集

- enqueue: 直接編集権限がないユーザーによる編集提案
- dequeue: ２つの「承認」ないし「却下」のいずれかのレビュー結果を得る or 「承認して編集」 or 「却下して編集」

## 参考

[What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)